# Trying to get several values from procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, procedure

I'm trying to use procedure like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    PROCEDURE `godating`.`realnames`(OUT rnames VARCHAR)
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
    | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
    | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
    | COMMENT 'string'*/
    BEGIN
    SELECT username INTO rnames FROM users GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*)>3
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I suppose there must be several values of username in rnames output. How can I improve my procedure to achive this goal?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE    PROCEDURE `godating`.`realnames`(In rnames varchar)  
    BEGIN
    SELECT username FROM licenses GROUP BY licenses_key having count(*)>0;
    END//

DELIMITER ;
===================
This procedure call like mysql query usind "call sp_name(rnames_values)".
```

Comment: creation causes an error:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  
        BEGIN
        SELECT username INTO rnames FROM users GROUP BY userna' at line 2